# Is the 要...了 grammar structure needed in 我还有很多要学习了?

Tags: grammar

If I am trying to convey to someone that I still have much to learn. The first thought that came to my mind was

> 我还有很多要学习了

But I am unsure if the 要...了 structure is necessary. Without it the sentence literally means "I still have a lot of learning" or am I am I reading that too literally? Also 要...了 more closely means "about to happen" so that makes the sentence more closely resemble "I still have a lot I'm about to learn" and that also sounds a bit silly. Is there a different grammar structure that would be more appropriate here or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Try 我还有很多东西要学 or 我还有很多东西需要学习。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct grammar would be “我还有很多要学习呢”. You may have heard “我要学习了”, which means "I'm about to go study", but the former sentence means "I still have a lot of learning to do." The difference is in “呢” and “了”

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to do some further research on the uses of 呢 since I only know of it from “。。。你呢？” and such

Comment: is 要...呢 the full structure or is just the 呢 necessary? What is the overarching use of 呢 in cases like this?

Comment: @小奥利奥 We recall "了" may mean "suggestion" or "aspect", but there is no natural interpretation in “我还有很多要学习了”, or do you have one interpretation in mind?

Comment: 要……呢 is commonly used when it's in the form ……还要……呢. For another example: ”她还要去上学呢。"

Comment: @Violapterin I know the grammar structure 要...了 implies that whatever falls between the 要 and the 了 has not yet happened and will happen in the near future

Comment: @DavidDong thank you

Comment: "要...了" is close to, I guess, "I am going to..." here, "了" modifies the verb, as in “我要学习了”. But "很多要学习的" can be seen as noun, this is why the phrase sounds less idiomatic. In “我还有很多要学习了” the "了" would modify "有", an existence claim, which is not suitable for such modal phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

活到老学道老。

or， more prosaic:

我还有很多要学习了。

Comment: 我还有很多要学习了 was why original wording, so that doesn't look weird to you?

Comment: Does not seem to answer OP's question.